# How do I get line coordinates from scratch?

Tags: java, math, graphics, logic, 2d

To start off, I want to say this is less of a syntax related question and more of a theory related question(Also I am working with Java, but the question/answer should be the same regardless of the language.). I want a function that has the parameters of x1, y1, x2, y2 (which are all integers). The function will take these and edit a 2d array (also integer) called pixelData[][]. Each coordinate that the line occupies will be added to pixelData in this format: pixelData[x][y];

For example: If the function worked properly and I called it with the following parameters:

```
int pixelData[][][];
pixelData = new int[10][10]; //grid size of 10x10;

x1 = 1;
y1 = 1;
x2 = 3;
y2 = 3;
```

The function would put the following values into pixel data:

```
pixelData[1][1] = 1;
pixelData[2][2] = 1;
pixelData[3][3] = 1;
```

For the math, my initial approach was to take the absolute value of x1-x2 and the absolute value of y1-y2 and put those is an int called xLength and yLength accordingly. Then I would store the ratio of the two (xLength/yLength) in a double called xyRatio. Then for every xyRatio x movements there is 1 y movement. The problem is that this only works for a handful of line angles, and mostly just produces inaccurate coordinates. For example, if the ratio is less than 1, there will be 0 change open the x axis every time the y axis changes, and other problems like that. If somebody could give me a formula or some help that would be great.

If you need any clarification on the question just ask. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am aware of the drawLine function, but I do not want to simply draw 
the line, I want a mapping of every coordinate. If there is an existing 
function that does what I need it to do, then PLEASE tell me about it.

-Ampck

Comment: Please choose one and only one language for your question. Else you risk being accused of language tag spamming, and that can bring down-votes and close-votes (for making the question too broad). So which is it: Java or C++? Please decide and [edit] your question.

Comment: Next, please clarify your question further. You appear to want an array of line coordinates, but **which coordinates**? Lines are composed of real number pairs, and there are a non-counting number infinite (greater than counting infinite, aleph-null,  -- e.g., the number of integers) number of these in a short line segment.

Comment: There are only a handful because I am only working with integers, which I thought was obvious since most of my variables (including where the pairs are being stored) were integers.

Comment: More importantly, show the relevant code where you show your best attempt at a solution. Then use this to clarify and improve your question, making it more specific.

Comment: There's too much of introduction. Please try to reduce it while adding a *specific question* or a clear description of *one* problem and what you have done so far to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some algorithm for [line rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

For example, look for the most popular [Bresenham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) algorithm

Implementation from [Rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Java) (replace `plot` with array entry filling)

```
private void drawLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        // delta of exact value and rounded value of the dependent variable
        int d = 0;

        int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
        int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);

        int dx2 = 2 * dx; // slope scaling factors to
        int dy2 = 2 * dy; // avoid floating point

        int ix = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1; // increment direction
        int iy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;

        int x = x1;
        int y = y1;

        if (dx >= dy) {
            while (true) {
                plot(g, x, y);
                if (x == x2)
                    break;
                x += ix;
                d += dy2;
                if (d > dx) {
                    y += iy;
                    d -= dx2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            while (true) {
                plot(g, x, y);
                if (y == y2)
                    break;
                y += iy;
                d += dx2;
                if (d > dy) {
                    x += ix;
                    d -= dy2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```